# How to Add new column containing ZScore in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update a column named [Z Score] to my table in SQL. I have written the code to create the new column in a SELECT query as shown below:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM (
       SELECT [Cardholder Name], [Transaction Date], [Merchant], 
       [Debit Amount], 
       (
        [Debit Amount] - 
        AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()
       ) as [ZScore]
       FROM ['PCard Output']
     ) cd;
```

That being said I am lost when it comes to using an UPDATE query to actually add the data to the column [Z Score]. I am using SQL Server 17. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readily do this with an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select cd.*,
             ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER () as new_ZScore
      from ['PCard Output'] cd
     )
update toupdate
    set ZScore = new_Zscore;
```

Comment: can you please clarify what "toupdate" should be? is it my table? I am getting an error "Incorrect syntax near 'cd'"

Comment: You need to remove the alias `cd` after the `CTE`

Comment: @Sami - looking at my table after running the above query I get different Zscores for every row, they also match the numbers from my select query.

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
UPDATE T
SET YourColumn = cd.[ZScore]
FROM 
(
    SELECT [Cardholder Name], 
           [Transaction Date], 
           [Merchant], 
           [Debit Amount], 
           ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
    FROM ['PCard Output']
) cd INNER JOIN YourTable T ON cd.ID = T.ID;
```

As a note I don't think you need the other columns you are selecting, so your query may look like:

```
UPDATE T
SET YourColumn = cd.[ZScore]
FROM 
(
    SELECT ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
    FROM ['PCard Output']
) cd INNER JOIN YourTable T ON cd.ID = T.ID;
```

or

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = 
(
    SELECT ([Debit Amount] - AVG([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) / (STDEV([Debit Amount]) OVER ()) as [ZScore]
    FROM ['PCard Output']
);
```

Comment: Upon further review I'm not sure that this works. I am getting the same Z_score for every row using this query, they should all be different numbers.